# Pandas df.to_sql() needs admin permission to append. And appending with admin permission replaces headlins

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I've a SQL Server database with several tables inside. All tables are created already, with auto-incremented key and all the columns I need.

Now I want to write additional rows to one table from a dataframe.

```py
def write_to_database(self, s_table, df):
    s_host = 'localhost'
    s_driver = 'SQL Server'
    port = 1433
    s_database = 'test'
    d_users = {
        'admin': ('censored', 'censored'),
        'user': ('censored', 'censored'),
    }
    s_username, s_pw = d_users.get('user', ('empty', 'empty'))
    mysql_engine = create_engine(
        f"mssql+pyodbc://{s_username}:{s_pw}@{s_host}:{port}/{s_database}?driver={s_driver}",
        pool_reset_on_return=None,  # disable default reset-on-return scheme
        use_setinputsizes=False
    )
        
    con = mysql_engine.connect()
    df.to_sql(name=f'type__{s_table}', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

But I get this exception:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database '{test'. (262) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I don't want to create a new table. I want to append to an existing one!

And when I use the admin credentials the existing table will replaced with a new one.

The new table has all the headlines (except for index) but all with type text and the auto incremented unique key isn't available anymore

Answer (score 0):

1. Permission error when using the 'user' credentials: The error message suggests that the user account specified does not have the necessary permissions to create a new table in the 'test' database. To resolve this, you should grant the 'user' account the required permissions to insert data into the existing table. You can do this using SQL Server Management Studio or by executing the appropriate SQL command to grant the INSERT permission on the target table to the 'user' account.
2. Replacing the existing table when using the 'admin' credentials: By default, the `to_sql` method in Pandas creates a new table if the specified table does not exist. If you want to append the data to an existing table, you should modify the `if_exists` parameter in your `to_sql` function call to 'append'. Additionally, you can specify the column data types in the destination table using the `dtype` parameter to ensure they match the original table structure.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def write_to_database(self, s_table, df):
    s_host = 'localhost'
    s_driver = 'SQL Server'
    port = 1433
    s_database = 'test'
    d_users = {
        'admin': ('censored', 'censored'),
        'user': ('censored', 'censored'),
    }
    s_username, s_pw = d_users.get('user', ('empty', 'empty'))
    mysql_engine = create_engine(
        f"mssql+pyodbc://{s_username}:{s_pw}@{s_host}:{port}/{s_database}?driver={s_driver}",
        pool_reset_on_return=None,  # disable default reset-on-return scheme
        use_setinputsizes=False
    )
    
    with mysql_engine.connect() as con:
        # Get the column data types from the existing table
        table_info = con.execute(f"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {s_table}")
        column_types = {column[0]: column[1] for column in table_info.cursor_description}
        
        # Append data to the existing table
        df.to_sql(name=s_table, con=con, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=column_types)
```

Make sure to replace `s_table` with the actual name of the target table. The code retrieves the column data types from the existing table and uses them when writing the DataFrame to ensure compatibility.

Comment: 1. I know what the exception message tells me, but I don't want to create this table. Because this table exists already. I just want to append the new rows at the end, what I tried to do with `if_exists='append'`

Comment: You can retrieve the existing table structure using SQLAlchemy's inspector object. Then, filter the DataFrame columns to match the existing table structure. Use the INSERT INTO SQL statement to append the DataFrame rows to the existing table.  from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

def write_to_database(self, s_table, df):
    s_host = 'localhost'
    s_driver = 'SQL Server'
    port = 1433
    s_database = 'test'
    d_users = {
        'admin': ('censored', 'censored'),
        'user': ('censored', 'censored'),
    }
    s_username, s_pw = d_users.get('user', ('empty', 'empty'))
    mysql_engine = create_engine(
        f"mssql+pyodbc://{s_username}:{s_pw}@{s_host}:{port}/{s_database}?driver={s_driver}",
        pool_reset_on_return=None,  # disable default reset-on-return scheme
        use_setinputsizes=False
    )
    
    with mysql_engine.connect() as con:
        inspector = inspect(con)
        
        if s_table not in inspector.get_table_names():
            raise ValueError(f"The table '{s_table}' does not exist in the database.")
        
        # Get the column information from the existing table
        columns = inspector.get_columns(s_table)
        column_names = [column['name'] for column in columns]
        
        # Filter DataFrame columns to match the existing table structure
        df = df[column_names]
        
        # Generate the INSERT INTO statement and append the data to the existing table
        insert_statement = f"INSERT INTO {s_table} ({', '.join(column_names)}) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        data = [tuple(row) for row in df.values.tolist()]
        con.execute(insert_statement, data)
```